# error: invalid type argument of '->' (have 'Personaggio')

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors

I have this problem while creating a function for moving a bot on a 16x16 Matrix, i want to subtract the coordinate x of Guardia with the coordinate Y of ladro.

Belowe is the code:

`

```
    typedef struct{
    int  nx;
    int  ny;
    }Personaggio;
Personaggio Ladro;
Personaggio Guardia;

void moveguardia(char scacchiera [][16], Personaggio *Guardia)

    {
          int movimento, GxMed, GyMed;
          if(scacchiera[Guardia->nx-1][Guardia->ny]=='m'){
            movimento=rand()%4;
            if(movimento==0){
              Guardia->nx=Guardia->nx+1;
              scacchiera[Guardia->nx-1][Guardia->ny]=' ';
              scacchiera[Guardia->nx][Guardia->ny]='G';
            }
        else if(movimento==1){
               Guardia->nx=Guardia->nx-1;
               scacchiera[Guardia->nx+1][Guardia->ny]=' ';
               scacchiera[Guardia->nx][Guardia->ny]='G';
        }
        else   if(movimento==2){
               Guardia->ny=Guardia->ny-1;
               scacchiera[Guardia->nx][Guardia->ny+1]=' ';
               scacchiera[Guardia->nx][Guardia->ny]='G';
        }
        else   if(movimento==3){
               Guardia->ny=Guardia->ny+1;
               scacchiera[Guardia->nx][Guardia->ny-1]=' ';
               scacchiera[Guardia->nx][Guardia->ny]='G';
        }
            }
        GxMed=abs((Guardia->nx) - (Ladro->nx));//error
```

the error is on this line GxMed=abs((Guardia->nx) - (Ladro->nx));//error

Please have a look at lines commented as error. I have searched a lot and also tried replacing -> by . but useless.`

Comment: `Ladro` is not a pointer.

Comment: If you replace `->` by `.`, which errort do yo get.

Comment: This is what is happening when you mix local and global variables with the same names and different types.

Comment: @MichaelWalz if i do this, i get this error: error: request for member 'nx' in something not a structure or union|

Comment: *...sigh...*..So I am guessing you have replaced it for `Guardia` as well...

Comment: I solved, i forgetted to pass  with a pointer Ladro at the function, thanks for the reply ;)

Comment: You did not change the name `Guardia` in the function parameter list?   This hides the global variable...  You have more bugs waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables inside the function do not know of the variables outside the function. The apparent issue seems to be that you initialized `Personaggio Ladro` outside the function. Your function has no idea of the existence of `Ladro` because you do not initialize such an object **inside** the function.